# Which was the fate of the Enterprise C in "Yesterday's Enterprise" alternate timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, time-travel

In TNG episode "Yesterday's Enterprise" the Enterprise C (the last starship with that name before TNG's time) travels in time 22 years to the future (TNG's present) just before being destroyed by the Romulans.

This event causes an alteration of the timeline and in the present of TNG, there is now a long war between the Federation and the Klingons, a war the Federation is losing. There the Enterprise C meets the Enterprise D.

We know the fate of the Enterprise C in the original timeline (being destroyed) but i dont remember any reference from the episode to what happened to the Enterprise C in the alternate timeline. Did she just disappeared 22 years ago or returned to the federation? People in Enterprise D should know her fate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It was presumed to be destroyed

Per [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/163.htm):

> Military log, Combat date 43625.2. While investigating an unusual
> radiation anomaly, the Enterprise has encountered what could almost be
> called a ghost from its own past, the Enterprise-C, the immediate
> predecessor to this battleship.
>
> [Bridge]
>
> (Only the Captain has a centre chair. Riker has to lean on the rail)
>
> DATA: Sensors confirm design and specifications, Captain. Analysis of
> hull and engine materials conform to engineering patterns and methods
> of that time period.
> WESLEY: (in full Starfleet uniform) But that
> cruiser was destroyed with all hands over twenty years ago.
> DATA:
> **Presumed destroyed. The Enterprise C was last seen near the Klingon
> outpost Narendra Three exactly twenty two years, three months and four
> days ago.**

Moreover:

> RIKER: There's **no record** of the Romulans ever assaulting the Enterprise C.

and:

> PICARD: It is possible that this exchange of fire was the catalyst for the formation of a temporal rift. **History has no record of your battle** with the Romulans.
>
> PICARD: The Narendra Three outpost was destroyed. It is regrettable that you did not succeed. A Federation starship rescuing a Klingon outpost might have averted twenty years of war.

It looks like the participation of USS Enterprise C in the Battle of Narenda III was unknown to the Federation and thay have not succeeded in rescuing the Klingon outpost.

Comment: There is no proof that Sela existed in the alternate timeline, therefore it is also possible that there were no survivors at all (everything is pure speculation).

Comment: Ah, yes, I misread, I thought they were asking about the alternate timeline created after Tasha was sent back.  The alternate alternate timeline.  My bad.

Comment: The ship may have survived, captured by the Romulans for study and it just was never reported. Tasha Yar was captured and had Sela. She died when she tried to escape. There first Officer (i forget his name) was also likely captured if the missions in Star Trek Online are to be believed. However, if that story is to be believed the C got pulled into multiple time adventures and so them being captured might be the ultimate fate, but not the full story.

Comment: @Durakken, as I said in my previous comment, everything is pure speculation